# Dynamically add data to GSON - Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to dynamically add values into class GetData, i.e. automatically pick up values from database: *@SerializedName()* and *public String* ...:

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class GetData {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public int id;
        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;
        @SerializedName("surname")
        public String surname;
        @SerializedName("school")
        public String school;
}
```

These values are hard-coded, so I get exact same values from database, and I want to make sure if user adds a new column in db, all data is visible to the app. How can I add values from table in database dynamically (as DB grows)?

Also, I am using Volley and FunDapter to bind dictionary like this:
[link to FunDapter]{https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter}

```
dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvID, new StringExtractor<GetData>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(GetData getData, int position) {
            return getData.name;
        }
    });
```

Comment: for the first, part, unless you are using some ORM (example ActiveAndroid) you will have to add a property in the class each time a  filed added to the database, the second part i did not understand, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: It is FunDapter library, that's how I fill values from my database.
[link](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter). Can you briefly explain how to add new data dinamically, every time database is changed?